# Supress cmd windows which open while C# program runs

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I have written a C# application, which communicates with C++ dll to process some things. The C++ .dll actually has some commands `system(TestApplication1)` , `system(TestApplication2)` etc.

While I run my C# application, and send a call to C++ function, these cmd windows open and close to do their work. Since my C# application is meant for a GUI front-end, I want to supress these windows from loading up.

I remmeber in C# when we load some process, we have the option to `pass ProcessWindowStyle=Hidden` in the arguments, but I am not sure how it can be done in this scenario.

I wouldn't prefer to make my application full screen, make it TopMost, and Maximized. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since the dll is the one that is spawning the processes, you don't have much control over how exactly they are spawned. Unless you also own the C++ code I don't think you can do anything.

Comment: @Jon: I have the C++ code too. Can something be done with these `system(Application)` commands to run these cmd windows in HiddenState?

Comment: Swap `CreateProcess` for `system` and do what it says here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780465/winapi-createprocess-but-hide-the-process-window