# Running an external exe from win32 application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am working on a WIN32 application in **Visual Studio 2010**. I have to execute an external exe from my code but don't have to show its window. along with executing the exe I am passing certain argument to exe. my code is given

```
char path[] = "D:\\scan\\scan.exe -l";
system(path);
//ShellExecute(hWnd, "open",path, NULL, NULL, SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
```

if I use system(path) it is executed properly but the window of the exe is also shown, but if I use ShellExecute(hWnd, "open",path, NULL, NULL, SWP_HIDEWINDOW); then the exe of the given path is not executed. 
how should I overcome this problem, kindly guide me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wants the program name and its parameters to be given separately. Try this:

```
ShellExecute(hWnd, NULL, "D:\\scan\\scan.exe", "-l", NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: SWP_HIDE -> you mean SW_HIDE surely?

Comment: @duDE: Typo fixed, ta.

Answer (score 3):

You should really use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) which does not use the shell to call a program. This also allows you to capture the program output and retrieve any error codes it might give.

If you need to hide the window of a GUI app, you can set `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` in the `dwFlags` in the `CreateProcess` call (cfr. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/780647/256138))

Comment: You're assuming the program is a console app.

Comment: @Jonathan see edit. Still no reason to go around to the shell. `ShellExecute` is useful for other things (see its docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx)), but it definitely is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Yeah I've used `ShellExecute` before :)