# Vala: Using Glib how can I spawn a command line without console in windows

Tags: windows, glib, vala, spawn

-X -mwindows flag in valac command line is insuficient because the program that I spawn is not builded with this flag.

Any Ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780465/winapi-createprocess-but-hide-the-process-window

Comment: Using glib? in vala?

Comment: I don't think it works *just* using GLib. You can call any C function from Vala so it should be possible to write a VAPI file that interfaces CreateProcessW or maybe one of the ShellExecute* APIs.

Comment: You could of course also write a "proxy application" in any other language that you call from the normal GLib spawn methods. Maybe there even is a ready made program for this task.

Comment: fwiw, [How to open/spawn a file with glib/gtkmm in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442189/how-to-open-spawn-a-file-with-glib-gtkmm-in-windows/45372515#45372515)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into GLib's (or GIO to be exact) `GSubprocess` API which is a wrapper around the respective on various operating systems:

https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSubprocess.html

Word of warning: needs a recent version of GIO (`>= 2.40`)

(this should have been a comment, but Im missing the reputation...)