# Using GTK3 link button under Windows

Tags: windows, gtk3, mingw-w64

I'm using the GTK3 and compiling under both Linux and Windows (with Mingw64), and I'm having a problem with the `GtkLinkButton`. I set a URI in my program and it works fine under Linux, but when I run it under Windows and click on the button nothing happens.

I've found the following documentation for [`gtk_show_uri_on_window`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Filesystem-utilities.html#gtk-show-uri-on-window), which does the actual work for `GtkLinkButton`:

> This is a convenience function for launching the default application to show the uri. The uri must be of a form understood by GIO (i.e. you need to install gvfs to get support for uri schemes such as http:// or ftp://, as only local files are handled by GIO itself).

Presumably this means I need to install GVFS under Mingw64. However saying `pacman -Ss gvfs` doesn't find any packages.

Is there a way to get URLs to work in GTK when running on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some digging I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442189/how-to-open-spawn-a-file-with-glib-gtkmm-in-windows) with a number of answers. It seems that the Right Thing is to copy the following executables into my application `bin` folder:

- `gspawn-win64-helper.exe`
- `gspawn-win64-helper-console.exe`