# Get SVN remote URL without using 'svn info' command

Tags: ruby, windows, svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

This question might be weird but I will explain why.

I am aware that `svn info` command displays the repository details where I can get the remote URL.

But in my situation I am running a background task on windows which is a ruby gtk2 application. When I do `svn info "#{url}"` it leads to opening a command prompt `cmd.exe` which just flashes on the screen for a second and disappears.

As this app is running as a windows service in the background and this command is scheduled for every few minutes, it keeps flashing the user's screen with a command prompt and disappears.

So would like to get the remote svn url in a way which does not involve doing `svn info` or figure a way to not flash the screen.

BTW i am using **Tortoise SVN** with command line arguments enabled. And the flashing command prompt is `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe`.

Any help will be really appreciated. :-)

Thanks

Comment: You can run the hided process?

Comment: I mean you can call svn info your_checkout --xml as hiden process and parse the xml, without any 'flashing'

Comment: Hiden - I mean hidden :(

Answer (score 2):

Run `svn info your_checkout --xml` as [hidden process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780465/winapi-createprocess-but-hide-the-process-window), and parse the results.