# Why program can be run from the command line, with Shellexecuteex it also works, but with CreateProcess it doesn't work?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createprocess

There is a program "prog.exe". It can be run from the command line:
`C:\Folder\prog.exe "D:\3.7.7\File.XML"`. I'm trying to do the same thing using `CreateProcess`. Program froze up, threw modal window with an error and terminated by timeout.

I tried to run using `ShellExecuteEx`. Program worked and finished correctly. But i can't use `ShellExecuteEx` because of problems with file association( error code 1155 ).

There are 2 questions:
1. Why program can be run from the command line, with `ShellExecuteEx` it also works, but with `CreateProcess` it doesn't work? Am I doing something wrong maybe?
2. Why program modal window is displayed? Why not hidden? Why are flags ignored:

```
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;  
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
```

But when i run another program, these flags work and hide GUI.

```
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
std::string cmd_line = "C:\\Folder\\prog.exe \"D:\\3.7.7\\File.XML\"";
const char *ss = (cmd_line.c_str());
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

LPSTR lp_str = const_cast<char *> (ss);
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, lp_str, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    std::ofstream  fs("D:\\3.7.7\\log.txt");
    fs << " Can't run prog.exe! ErrorCode: " << GetLastError();
    fs.close();
}
std::ofstream  fs("D:\\3.7.7\\log.txt");
fs << "Run correctly \n";

switch (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 20000))
{
case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
    return;

case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
    TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    fs << " Waiting to long. Terminate process ";
    break;

case WAIT_FAILED:
    fs << " Waiting failed. ErrorCode: " << GetLastError();
    break;
}
fs.close();
```

Comment: You should show actual code rather than this fake code. Then we could see what you actually pass to `CreateProcess` rather than having to guess at what `ss` is. Your use of `const_cast` should be a great big warning sign to you. If something is not `const`, then applying `const_cast` does not make it so! You might get away with this with `CreateProcessA` due to a quirk of implementation, but it's a very bad habit to form. Furthermore, if you encounter an error, you have to tell us the details of that error. Make sure we have as much information as you do, and the same code as you.

Comment: Does the behavior of the program being run depend on the working directory? You can try C++ statement `__debugbreak();` in the beginning of the program being run, so to debug it and see what's wrong after it's run using `CreateProcess`.

Comment: I think you want it to run a console program in hidden mode, using `CreateProcess`. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780465/winapi-createprocess-but-hide-the-process-window (see `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`)

Comment: What is the actual error that `CreateProcess()` is reporting? What does the modal window actually say/look like? When `CreateProcess()` fails, you are calling `GetLastError()` too late. You must call it before doing anything else. But you are opening a file before calling `GetLastError()`, so the act of opening that file can wipe out the error code that was set by `CreateProcess()`. Also, your code is still proceeding with its success logic (logging "Run correctly" and waiting on `hProcess `) if `CreateProcess()` fails, which is clearly wrong.