# Is it possible to launch command line application without displaying its window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an command line application that has `wmain()` entry point. And I launch it from another app using `ShellExecuteEx` function. If I set `shellExecuteInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE` it still pops out. Is it somehow possible to not show it at all?

Comment: Use a better function: CreateProcess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780465/winapi-createprocess-but-hide-the-process-window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CreateProcess` and pass the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag.

Comment: It works until you need to launch process that requires elevation. The only way then is to compile command line application as windows app(with `winmain` entry point). And use `ShellExecuteEx`. :)

Comment: There are a few options in that scenario depending on your requirements