# How to display cmd prompt after printing output to cmd.exe?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cmd

I have an `winmain` application that is executed from `cmd.exe` and prints output to it. I atach to the cmd.exe using `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`. After application is executed and output is printed to `cmd.exe` command line prompt is not displayed and it looks like application is stil running(while it is already closed). Before closing my application I release the console using `FreeConsole()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

int wWinMain
(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
) 
    {
    AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);

    std::wofstream console_out("CONOUT$");
    std::wcout.rdbuf(console_out.rdbuf());

    std::wcout << L"\nSome Output" << std::endl;

    FreeConsole();

    return 0;
    }
```

Current result:
[image]

My goal:[image]

How should I make prompt `C:New folder>` appear after `myapp.exe` has printed its output and is closed.

Comment: Showing a [mcve] would certainly help. It doesn't sound like that should take more than 3 lines of code.

Comment: My bad. Added code example.

Comment: I am not convinced that this is the right solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788851/is-it-possible-to-launch-command-line-application-without-displaying-its-window

Comment: Could you mention other ways to solve it, because as far as my research has gone(and I did try my hardest) I've come to conclusion that it is the only way if you want to have application that: 1. Requires elevation 2. In some cases needs to be launched from command line and print output to it. 3. In other cases needs to be launched from other application and make no appearance.

Comment: You are calling `FreeConsole` while your *console_out* object still references it. I don't know if this errors out, but neither do you, since you aren't interested in the return value from [FreeConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150.aspx).

Comment: I've used debugger to check if it returns success value and it does.

Comment: The use of `wWinMain()` shows that the system thinks the program is a windowed application, and thus `cmd.exe` will begin prompting for more commands right away. Your extra message doesn't change anything; it will just shove the user input down a few lines. The console will still be waiting for a command from the earlier prompt. What are you really trying to accomplish by doing this, in the long term?

Comment: Can't you make it a console app rather than a GUI app so this is unnecessary?

Comment: @jcoder If I make it as console app, it is impossible to completely hide it when launching with `ShellExecuteEx` from other application.

Comment: Why don't you launch it using `CreateProcess` then?

Comment: @IInspectable You cannot launch an executable that requires elevation using `CreateProcess`. :(

Comment: Place the code that requires elevation into its own module, manifested with `requireAdministrator`, and keep using `CreateProcess`. Or use the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx).

Comment: If I were you I would ask about your problem rather than your solution.

Comment: @IInspectable Is it possible to launch an application that requires elevation from non elevated process using `CreateProcess`? Because if I set requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" and try to launch that `.exe` using `CreateProcess` I get error code 740 - The requested operation requires elevation.

Comment: @LosBlancoo: Not with `CreateProcess()`, no.  See [How to run application which requires admin rights from one that doesn't have them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586139/).  Also see [Vista UAC: The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide) and its `CreateProcessElevated()` helper function.

Comment: I'm fairly convinced that the implementation for `ShellExecuteEx` doesn't use any secret OS internals, but calls `CreateProcess` at some point. It may not be a simple matter of calling `CreateProcess`, but it should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

In case the question has not been answered yet (after such a long time), it is required to simulate the actual pressing of the 'Enter' key in the console window by sending (or, preferably, posting) the corresponding WM_KEYDOWN message to the console window, i.e.

after
`std::wcout << L"\nSome Output" << std::endl;`

and before calling 
`FreeConsole()`, 
insert the following:

```
HWND hWndCon_ = ::GetConsoleWindow();
 if( hWndCon_ ) {
    ::PostMessage( hWndCon_, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0 );
 }
```

or simply

`::PostMessage( ::GetConsoleWindow(), WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0 );`