# How to display the default command prompt after writing some output to an attached console?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-console

When a graphical application connects to the parent console with `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)` and writes some output, it leaves the console with a blank line.

```
PS C:\>my_program.exe
some output
more output
```

Instead of leaving the console with a blank line, I want to reset the console prompt after exiting the application.

```
PS C:\>my_program.exe
some output
more output
PS C:\>
```

Is there a way to achieve this, and if yes how?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable I want to create an application that shows some additional startup information when launched from a console but doesn't open a console on its own. So I created a windows application and call AttachConsole to attach to the parent console if it exists to output some lines there.
However this leaves the console with a blank line, making it unrecognizable when the output is done.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974182/how-to-display-cmd-prompt-after-printing-output-to-cmd-exe?rq=1, so it would be great if there were another possible way.

Comment: *A process can use the FreeConsole function to detach itself from its console.*

Comment: @JonathanPotter FreeConsole doesn't reset the prompt alas

Comment: All that my_program.exe and powershell.exe have in common is that they're attached to the same console session (i.e. an instance of conhost.exe). The console I/O of my_program.exe has nothing directly to do with the powershell.exe, which simply writes its shell prompt and waits for console input.

Comment: *"I couldn't reproduce the solution from ..."*. I can solve it with this solution, before `FreeConsole`. Could share the reason that couldn't reproduce it?